# Do i have to join apple's developer program in order to run anypic code on Xcode 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I've discovered whenever i open the Xcode project of atypic-ios...
it shows nothing but a yellow warning sign that saids "No matching code signing identity found" and when i press the 'fix issue' button it appears with an box saying that "To resolve code signing issues, you need to add an APPLE ID that is enrolled to an apple developer program'...
tried everything to compile it, however not succeeded. 
any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal -

According to the [Apple code-signing info here](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/code-signing/),

> Before your Mac app or iOS app can be used with store services, installed on an iOS device for development or testing, or submitted to the App Store, it must be signed with a certificate issued by Apple.

So, if you want to run your app on a physical device, you need code signing, and as such, to be enrolled in the apple developer program.

If you don't want to enroll, you should be able to run the app in the iOS simulater on your computer. This does not require your code to be signed. Have you tried running in the simulater?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No you just have to set any bundle id in Project target like com.parse.anypic than your application start in simulator but dot forgot to change

```
// [Parse setApplicationId:@"APPLICATION_ID" clientKey:@"CLIENT_KEY"];
```

in AppDelegate.m file with your APPLICATION_ID and CLIENT_KEY